# Listings code snippet has white horizontal lines across it

Tags: listings

I'm using the `listings` package to typeset my code examples. I've set the background color to slightly off white color and I'm noticing strange white horizontal lines across the snippet. They seem to go right between every line.

Not sure if I should include my `listings` settings?

[image: Listings bug]

Comment: Including your settings is a great idea, it'd be even better if you included a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem and that narrows down your code to only that which is necessary to recreate your problem.

Comment: @doncherry: I was thinking about adding it when I wrote the question but then I kinda forgot... (was tired, last 2 weeks until hand-in)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The background color and the frame are drawn for every line separately. `listings` assumes a certain line height and such graphic errors appear if the real height is larger than that. From your image I would guess you are using a larger font for the line numbers than for the normal text. You should set `numberstyle` to the same or smaller size than the normal text.

In my test I get the same white lines if the `numberstyle` is larger than the `basicstyle` (left) but not if it is smaller (right) or the same size.

[image: Comparison]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize,numberstyle=\large,backgroundcolor=\color{black!20},numbers=left,frame=lrtb]
    some code
    more code
    more code
    more code
    more code
    more code
    more code
    more code
    more code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hspace{2cm}%
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize,numberstyle=\tiny,backgroundcolor=\color{black!20},numbers=left,frame=lrtb]
    some code
    more code
    more code
    more code
    more code
    more code
    more code
    more code
    more code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: One might also say `numberstyle=\mymacro` after having defined `\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\smash{#1}}`, because `numberstyle=<x>` executes `\def\lst@numberstyle{<x>}` and this command is called as `\lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}`. Additional formatting may be included in `\mymacro` (the name of this macro can be different, of course), for example for changing color.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I don't remember seeing anything about this in `listings` documentation...

Comment: I have this issue without using line numbers. The white lines are very fine and their visibility depends on the zoom level in the PDF reader.

Comment: @h0b0: That seems to be a PDF reader issue. Getting such artifacts depending on the zoom level is a well known issue with them. You could place the listing into a `{adjustbox}{bgcolor=<your color>}` environment (`adjustbox` package) instead, so that the background is drawn as one block.

Comment: I get the same issue in Okular and Evince... I think it is not a PDF reader connected.

Comment: @71GA: Okular and Evince might use the same internal PDF library or simply use the same or similar enough zooming algorithm. You can adjust the style to make the numbers more visible, but it will always be viewer dependent, IMHO.

Comment: @h0b0 Your solution prevents listings to wrap at the page break.

Comment: @71GA: Are you also using the `minipage` environments as with in the example? They do not break across pages. Without them it should work.