# Listings lstlisting environment has white horizontal lines

Tags: listings

I have sort of the same problem as the user `benregn` in

[Listings code snippet has white horizontal lines across it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18303/listings-code-snippet-has-white-horizontal-lines-across-it)

. But making the `numberstyle` smaller than the `basicstyle` does not solve my problem.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{myStyle}
{
    tabsize=4,
    autogobble=true,
    mathescape=true,
    numbers=left,
    xleftmargin=9mm,
    framexleftmargin=9mm,
    commentstyle=\color{green!50!black},
    comment=[l]\%\ ,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!10!white},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    keywords=
    {
        and,
        and,
        case,
        do,
        else,
        elseif,
        end,
        for,
        function,
        if,
        switch,
        to,
        while,
    }
}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=myStyle]
        $abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$
        $\left\lfloor \frac{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\right\rfloor$
    \end{lstlisting}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The result looks like

[image]

. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is documented in the listings manual.

```
8.2 Listings with a background colour and LATEX escaped
formulas
```

> At the moment there is only one workaround: • Write your code into an
>   external file `<filename>`. • Input your code by `\lstinputlisting{<filename>}`
>   into your document and surround it with a frame generated by
>   \begin{mdframed} . . . \end{mdframed}.

This being said, I tried the shorter route and it appears to work, but no idea if it really does work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{myStyle}
{
    tabsize=4,
    autogobble=true,
    mathescape=true,
    numbers=left,
    xleftmargin=9mm,
    framexleftmargin=9mm,
    commentstyle=\color{green!50!black},
    comment=[l]\%\ ,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    keywords=
    {
        and,
        and,
        case,
        do,
        else,
        elseif,
        end,
        for,
        function,
        if,
        switch,
        to,
        while,
      }
}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=black!10!white]
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=myStyle]
        #test&&#$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$
        $\left\lfloor \frac{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\right\rfloor$
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}

    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]