# How do I remove these white bars in the listing environment?

Tags: listings

Basically I am trying to add some code to my document, and no matter what I try to do, these white lines won't go.[image: There are these weird white lines].

I don't seem to be the only one struggling with this as I found this question, [Listings code snippet has white horizontal lines across it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18303/listings-code-snippet-has-white-horizontal-lines-across-it), but trying the solution there didn't fix my issue. No matter what size options I choose, the white lines stay.

I am using miktex with pdflatex. I also tried with xetex and lualatex but that hasn't helped the issue either.

Hopefully someone can help me with this. All of the relevant code below...

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\definecolor{codegray}{HTML}{F8F8F2}
\definecolor{codestring}{HTML}{FFFFB6}
\definecolor{codenormal}{HTML}{F8F8F2}
\definecolor{codekeyword}{HTML}{FBB036}
\definecolor{codecomment}{HTML}{5C98CD}
\definecolor{backcolour}{HTML}{2B3E50}


\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codecomment},
    keywordstyle=\color{codekeyword},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codestring},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{codenormal},
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=false,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{}
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\underline{#1}}
\newcommand{\uuvec}[1]{\hat{\underline{#1}}}
\newcommand{\icol}[1]{% inline column vector
  \left[\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}\right]%
}

\newcommand{\irow}[1]{% inline row vector
  \begin{matrix}[#1]\end{matrix}%
}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={150mm,227mm},
 left=30mm,
 top=35mm,
 }

 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries\raggedleft}
   {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
 % ------ einde chapter headings aanpassen


\begin{document}
\chapter*{Huiswerk Week 4}
 
%some irrelevant document code here...

\section*{Python Code}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Created on Wed Sep 23 13:49:15 2020

'''

import numpy as np
import math as m
import sympy as s
s.init_printing(use_latex=True, forecolor='White')

def latex(obj):
    print(s.latex(obj))

# ----- define symbols for symbolic maths -----
# alle symbolen hier, dus ook voor latere opgaves
psi = s.Function('\\psi')('t')
phi = s.Function('\\varphi')('t')
theta = s.Function('\\theta')('t')

psi_dot = s.Function('\\dot{\\psi}')('t')
phi_dot = s.Function('\\dot{\\varphi}')('t')
theta_dot = s.Function('\\dot{\\theta}')('t')

omegax = s.Symbol('\\omega_{x}')
omegay = s.Symbol('\\omega_{y}')
omegaz = s.Symbol('\\omega_{z}')

px = s.Symbol('p_x')
py = s.Symbol('p_y')
pz = s.Symbol('p_z')

alias = {psi.diff('t'):psi_dot, phi.diff('t'): phi_dot, theta.diff('t'): theta_dot}
# ----- rotatie matrices hier -----
fCn_np = np.array([[s.cos(psi), s.sin(psi), 0],
                       [-s.sin(psi), s.cos(psi), 0],[0,0,1]])
fCn = s.Matrix(fCn_np)

gCf_np = np.array([[s.cos(theta), 0, -s.sin(theta)],[0,1,0],
                       [s.sin(theta), 0, s.cos(theta)]])
gCf = s.Matrix(gCf_np)

bCg_np = np.array([[1,0,0],[0, s.cos(phi), s.sin(phi)],
                       [0, -s.sin(phi), s.cos(phi)]])
bCg = s.Matrix(bCg_np)

# ----- nodige vector definities hier -----
g_g1_np = np.array([1,0,0])
g_g1 = s.Matrix(g_g1_np)

f_f2_np = np.array([0,1,0])
f_f2 = s.Matrix(f_f2_np)

n_n3_np = np.array([0,0,1])
n_n3 = s.Matrix(n_n3_np)


# ----- calculating angular velocities here for deel 1.c. -----
b_w_bn =( (phi_dot * bCg * g_g1) + (theta_dot * bCg * gCf * f_f2) +
            (psi_dot * bCg * gCf * fCn * n_n3))

# ----- deel 1.d. -----
res = s.solve((b_w_bn[0] - omegax, b_w_bn[1] - omegay, b_w_bn[2] - omegaz),
              (psi_dot, theta_dot, phi_dot))


# ----- deel 1.h. -----
# definities van nodige rotatie matrices en vectoren [.T neemt de getransponeerde]
b_r_pc = s.Matrix(np.array([px,0,0]))
gCb = bCg.T
fCg = gCf.T
nCf = fCn.T

g_r_pc = gCb * b_r_pc
f_r_pc = fCg * gCb * b_r_pc
n_r_pc = nCf * fCg * gCb * b_r_pc


# ----- deel 1.i. -----
# N triad
def ntriad():
    n_dr_pc = s.diff(n_r_pc, 't')
    n_w_nn = s.Matrix([0,0,0]) # geen rotatie matrix
    n_dr_n = (n_dr_pc + n_w_nn.cross(n_r_pc)).subs(alias)
    return s.simplify(n_dr_n)

# F triad
def ftriad():
    f_w_fn = fCn*(psi_dot*n_n3)
    f_dr_pc = s.diff(f_r_pc, 't')
    f_dr_n = (f_dr_pc + f_w_fn.cross(f_r_pc))
    n_dr_n = (nCf*f_dr_n).subs(alias)
    return s.simplify(n_dr_n)

# G triad
def gtriad():
    g_w_gn = theta_dot*gCf*f_f2 + psi_dot*gCf*fCn*n_n3
    g_dr_pc = s.diff(g_r_pc, 't')
    g_dr_n = (g_dr_pc + g_w_gn.cross(g_r_pc))
    n_dr_n = (nCf*fCg*g_dr_n).subs(alias)
    return s.simplify(n_dr_n)

# B triad
def btriad():
    # b_w_bn is al gedefinieerd in deel c
    b_dr_pc = s.diff(b_r_pc, 't')
    b_dr_n = (b_dr_pc + b_w_bn.cross(b_r_pc))
    n_dr_n = (nCf*fCg*gCb*b_dr_n).subs(alias)
    return s.simplify(n_dr_n)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a complete code, not just a snippet.

Comment: You get better backgrounds using `tcolorbox` instead of the `listings` method.

Comment: @Bernard I added everything thatv was relevant

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159569/listing-background-broken-by-colorbox-and-framebox/159602?r=SearchResults&s=1|25.0528#159602